# Geolocating dataset of well pumps?

Tags: coordinate-system, land-survey

I have a dataset of well pumps, and I am trying to geolocate them. Each of the wells has as "Service Address" field, but instead of giving an address, it lists something that looks like this: "NW NE SW 27 22 23" or "SW SW SW 10 23 23" or even "NW NW NW NW 7 23 21", though maybe that last one is a typo.

Are these spatial coordinates of some type?

It seems a bit like an Aliquot part, but the fact that it's (usually) 3 directions and 3 numbers make me think it must be something different.

Comment: Not a coordinate system, but a referencing model. Research "Public Land Survey System"

Comment: For example: NW NE SW 27 22 23 = the NW 1/14 of the NE 1/4 of the SW 1/4 of Section 27 in Township 22/Range 23.

Comment: @cl3 Thank you, you are exactly correct. I spent some time researching the PLSS, but I didn't find anything that used the notation I was looking at. Fortunately, I knew the general area of the wells so I was able to fill in the remaining information.